# HttpClient configured in Program.cs is not being passed to MediatR RequestHandler by dependency injection container

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, mediatr

I'm working on a Blazor WebAssembly application in .NET 6.0.

I'm using MediatR requests and handlers.

```
public class DummyRequest : IRequest<string>
{
    public Guid Test { get; } = new Guid("e9f41a5d-5da6-4aad-b118-83476b7f40f4");
}


public class DummyHandler : IRequestHandler<DummyRequest, string>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    public DummyHandler(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(httpClient));
    }

    public async Task<string> Handle(DummyRequest request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
      // This should be the value configured in Program.cs
        string baseAddress = _httpClient.BaseAddress?.AbsoluteUri ?? string.Empty;
        // But it's always blank, so we can't make any calls with the HttpClient

        await Task.CompletedTask;
        return "foobar";
    }
}
```

I'm configuring a different HttpClient for each request handler in Program.cs, then I'm adding MediatR:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient<DummyHandler>((client) => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.somewhere.com"); });
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I have also tried reversing those calls, so that I add MediatR first, and register the HttpClient for the DummyHandler type afterwards.

At runtime, after that Handler has been instantiated, it should have an `_httpClient` with a `BaseAddress` property set to "https://api.somewhere.com".

However, it always gets an HttpClient with a null BaseUri, so the Handler can't use the HttpClient in any operations.

Can anybody see what's gone wrong please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that MediatR registers interface-implemetation pair so you need to follow the same pattern for the typed client registration. Try the following:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<IRequestHandler<DummyRequest, string>, DummyHandler>((client) => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.somewhere.com"); });
```

[Gist](https://gist.github.com/gurustron/7ce9302894bcddef294067b3009efbf7) with full test code.

Comment: Have you actually tried this? I've been having trouble with injecting HttpClient like this and nothing I try seems to work.

Comment: Here is an example of what I mean. https://dotnetfiddle.net/a6dPu5

Comment: @DavidG remove `builder.Services.AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();` or place it before the httpclient registration, cause otherwise it will override the registration by the `AddHttpClient`.

Comment: @DavidG https://dotnetfiddle.net/dhCPx1

Comment: Ugh, that's a bit of nasty hidden behaviour. I mean, I get why it needs to be that way, but it's very confusing.

Comment: @DavidG agreed.

Comment: Anyway, have an upvote  

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, GuruStron. It is exactly what I was looking for. I got it working now. It is such a useful code snippet that it should be on the MediatR README.md on GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a *typed* httpclient, you could use a [*named* httpclient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests#named-clients).

Thus register as

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("somename", client => { client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.somewhere.com"); });
```

And in the constructor, inject the httpclientfactory instead:

```cs
    public DummyHandler(HttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClientFactory.CreateClient("somename");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to create the wrapper class around your Http client and register it instead.It hides **implementation** of your connection type and can be extended by other logic or other realization if you need.

Example:

```
class ApiConnection : IConnection
{
  private readonly HttpClient _client;

  public ApiConnection(...)
{
  _client = new HttpClient();
}
// some other logic

}
```

Add this class to your Handler (IConnection connection) and use it in handler.

```
Register as: services.AddSingleton<IConnection, APIConnection>();
```

Comment: Bad idea, you'll quickly exhaust the sockets.

Comment: @JHBonarius lol what?

Comment: Httpclient is reentrant. This you should use one static instance or a pool. If you don't know the MediatR handler lifetime, not the exact purpose of HttpClientFactory, I'm afraid you cannot help here.

Comment: @JHBonarius Wrapper has private readonly field HttpClient. Wrapper is singleton. What are you talking about? handler's lifetime should be configured in other places

Comment: Yeah, so what happens when you set the BaseAddress for that single instance? Everything that uses it will have that same base address. HttpClientFactory manages all that for you. That's the reason the OP is asking about it.

Comment: @JHBonarius pass URL segments in methods wrapper and update URL inside on some GetAsync(string path) call for example.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions and interesting discussion, @JHBonarius and IKomarovLeonid.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using the `IRequestHandler<SomeCommand>` alternative where there is no response, MediatR internally converts it to to `IRequestHandler<SomeCommand, Unit>`, which is what you will need to use to properly inject the HTTP client in your DI:

```cs
serviceCollection
    .AddHttpClient<IRequestHandler<SomeCommand, Unit>, SomeCommandHandler>((httpClient) =>
    {
        ...
    });
```